# Music21 AttributeError: module 'importlib' has no attribute 'util'

Tags: python, installation, pycharm, music21

I'm trying to get started using music21 in python. I've imported the package into PyCharm but when I use the line:

```
import music21
```

at the start of my file, it gives me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  
File "C:/Users/Miles/Documents/Miles/Uni/Coding/Music21/Start.py", line 1, in <module>
    import music21
  
File "C:\Users\Miles\Documents\Miles\Uni\Coding\Music21\venv\Environment\lib\site-packages\music21\__init__.py", line 169, in <module>
    
from music21 import base  # noqa: E402
  
File "C:\Users\Miles\Documents\Miles\Uni\Coding\Music21\venv\Environment\lib\site-packages\music21\base.py", line         119, in <module>

loader = importlib.util.find_spec(modName)
AttributeError: module 'importlib' has no attribute 'util'
```

It works fine when I try to run it from the python console, and I'm using python 3.7 and music21 version 6.5 which should be compatible so not sure where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed in the unreleased version (current development branch on GitHub).

See this issue and linked PR:
https://github.com/cuthbertLab/music21/issues/750

Answer (score 0):

Since you are saying it works for you in python console, I suggest installing music21 package in PyCharm. Refer the following document for installing packages in PyCharm.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I should have said I've already installed the package unfortunately.